# How to add Microsoft Clarity Filter Custom Tags using React Native?

Tags: react-native, ms-clarity

I read the Microsoft Clarity documentation and I found there we can add Custom Tag for our web Project, As Microsoft Clarity Support android also has React Native SDK, But I couldn't found there is any way to add Custom Tag in React Native android.
Although I found library react-native-clarity but there is also no way to add Custom filter Tag.
Can anyone help me in this If there is any way to add Custom Tag in React Native it's appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Microsoft Clarity Documentation Link: [How to setup custom Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/filters/custom-tags#how-to-setup-custom-tags)

This is an example how to add Custom filter Tag for web:

```
clarity("set", "key", "value");
```

I want this type of solution for React Native android.
Here is How Custom Filter Tag show on Microsoft clarity dashboard image is show in below:

[image]